# Some questions about calculation central charge in a CFT in $d$ spacetime dimensions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, ads-cft, central-charge

This is based on this paper, http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0212138

- For a CFT on a $S^d$ spacetime (of radius R) it seems to be claimed that the central charge is given by, $ c = \langle \int_{S^d_R} d^dx \sqrt{g} T_\mu ^\mu  \rangle $
- Their equation 23 (on page 6) seems to indicate that if $W = -log Z$ is the free energy of the theory then it further follows that, $c = \frac{1}{d}R \frac{\partial }{\partial R} W$ (...I believe that the derivative is being evaluated at the value of the radius of the sphere..)
- Just below equation 26 it is claimed that, "...the central charge can be read off from the coefficient of log R in an expansion of W[R]..."

I would like to know the proof/derivation of three methods that have been spelt out to calculate the central charge of a CFT.

Comment: "Method" $3$ is an obvious consequence of Method  $2$ ($c = \frac{1}{d}R \frac{\partial }{\partial R} W$). If you get $W = a Log R +b$, you will have $c=\frac{a}{d}$

Comment: @Trimok Isn't your argument just one-way? What if it were $W = aR^2 + bR$? Then $c = (R/d)(2aR + b)$. I don't get what you are saying. Firstly one can't have a term like "log(R)" in $W$ since $R$ has dimensions and one can't take log of something with dimensions. So even if such a log term arises it will come compensated with some scale to make the argument dimensionless. So it can still be something like, $W = alog(\Lambda R) + bR^2 + cR$ say and then this method-3 will not work!.  And also why should such a "log(R)" term be natural?

Comment: @Trimok One way the things can match up is if in the method-3 there is an implicit limit of $R \rightarrow 0$..but why should that be?

Comment: If you look at expressions $(36), (40), (48),(50)$, you see that $V_1$ and $V_2$ ($W_f \sim V_1+V_2$), respect the expression $(a \log R+b)$.

Comment: @Trimok But aren't these 3 methods quoted there a general statement about all CFTs? Or are they also claiming that this $a log (\Lambda R) + b$ is the general form for all $Ws$ for CFTs? [...you might have a look at this related question that I had asked - http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/73612/about-the-general-expression-of-trace-anomaly-and-cft-partition-functions?rq=1 ... ]

Comment: In the large $R$ limit (see text between equations $26$ and $27$), $fR^{d-2\Delta} \to \infty$ , that is $fg_l \to \infty$, we may replace, in equation $25$, $\log (1+fg_l)$ by $\log (fg_l)$, and, in equation $24$, we have $g_l \sim R^{d-2\Delta}$, so we naturally get $\log R$ terms in the large $R$ limit.

Comment: @Trimok hmm..that is interesting..so they are using this $f$ coupling in the Lagrangian to set a scale for what is "large" and "small" R and arguing that in the large R limit W is always logarithmic in R...is that so? So they are making an asymptotic statement that for CFTs on any dimensional sphere in the limit of large radius W will always asymptotically scale as log R...right?[...but this argument also means that in the limit of small radius or no double-trace deformation the free energy of the CFT vanishes..how does one understand that?..]

Comment: @Trimok It would be great to know of your views on the other points too.. :)

Comment: @Trimok Also I would wonder how many of these statements are special about $S^d$..wonder what happens to these statements if one is on say $\mathbb{H}^{d-1} \times S^1$ - a natural space for the CFT to live in from the point of view of entanglement entropy.

Comment: Although it does not concern the sphere, and it is in the special context of string theory ($d=2$), there is an interesting paragraph in [David Tong course](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.0333v3.pdf), p $82-89$, Chapters $4.1,4.4.1,4.4.2,4.4.3$, about the relations between the central charge $c$, $<T^\mu_\mu>$, and the partition function $Z$.